# If strange matter exists, what about bottom matter?

Tags: standard-model, quarks

So if we have neutronium under immense pressure, I understand that it can disassociate into a plasma of 1 third up quarks, 2 thirds down quarks, and supposedly gluons.  If half of those down quarks can convert into strange quarks, we get strange matter, which can now be compressed far further than neutronium due to the decreased outward degeneracy pressure, since we now have three kinds of particles that can occupy the same energy state without violating the Pauli Exclusion Principle.  If I'm missing any points up to now please correct me.  The questions I haven't been able to answer yet include:

1. What is the actual process that would theoretically allow this transformation?  It seems like it tends to go in the other direction, strange quarks decaying into down quarks instead of the other way around.  What would cause a down quark to take on the more massive, less stable form of the strange quark?
2. For charge conservation, the down quarks could not turn into top or charm quarks.  This doesn't preclude bottom quarks, however.  Strange matter sounds cooler and less juvenile than "bottom matter," but is there any other reason I'm not hearing physicists talk about that?

Comment: Without energetics, this is a bit like singing about architecture. The Pauli exclusion pressure among *d*s is relieved by converting half of them to *s*, and your energetics should give you an advantage bigger than the *s* - *d* mass difference, but presumably smaller than the *b* - *d* mass difference. But your source should give you the numbers: the devil is in the details.

Comment: Background [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_matter#Strange_matter_that_is_only_stable_at_high_pressure).